# What is the effect of "/proc/$pid/latency" file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, latency, proc

I find there is a `/proc/$pid/latency` file on my **SuSE Enterprise Linux 12**. E.g.:

```
# cat /proc/1476/latency
Latency Top version : v0.1
```

But from [proc manual](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman5/proc.5.html), I can't find any info about this `/proc/$pid/latency` file. After googling, I just find this [old page](http://lwn.net/Articles/265945/), and http://www.latencytop.org/ can't be opened now.

So my question is what is the effect of `/proc/$pid/latency` file ? Only shows the `Latency Top version`? Since http://www.latencytop.org/ is broken now, what is the status of `Latency Top`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick grep on fs/proc reveals how to enable the thing - `sysctl kernel.latencytop=1`. Afterwards you can check results with latencytop.

It definitely looks quite dead though.